# Deploy java REST service on tomcat docker

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy a simple REST service to a tomcat that is running on a docker, but I can't seam to reach the service that I tried to deploy.

The simple service that I created is in this class:

```
@Path("/test")
public class RestTest {

    public static final String JSON_RPC = "2.0";

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response processHelloRequestGet() {
        String answer = "Hello There!";
        JsonRpcResponse rpcResponse = new JsonRpcResponse();
        rpcResponse.setId("42");
        rpcResponse.setJsonRpc(JSON_RPC);
        rpcResponse.setResult(answer);
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(rpcResponse).build();
    }
}
```

It just creates a simple, static answer in form of a JSON-RPC response.

My `web.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>REST Test</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>net.jfabricationgames.rest_test</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.jfabricationgames.rest_test</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestTest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RestTest Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JAX-RS for REST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-m07</version><!-- <version>2.0</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version><!-- <version>2.10.1</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version><!-- <version>2.10.1</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version><!-- <version>2.10.1</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
            <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
            <version>0.99</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>RestTest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/rest_test</path>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now if I run the project on a tomcat server **from within eclipse everything is working just as expected** (using the run configuration `Base directory: ${workspace_loc:/RestTest}` and `Goals: tomcat7:run`) and I can reach the service using the URL `http://localhost:8080/rest_test/rest/test/hello`.

**The problem** now is that I want my service to run on a tomcat inside a docker on a server, which doesn't seem to be working.

**What I tried so far** is exporting the project into a .war file (using maven (gloals: clean install compile) or the eclipse export function), placing them in the directory from where I build the docker file, creating the docker file and running it.

The `Dockerfile` I'm using (following [this tutorial](https://aspetraining.com/resources/blog/deploying-your-first-web-app-to-tomcat-on-docker)) looks like this:

```
FROM tomcat:8.0-alpine
LABEL maintainer="deepak@softwareyoga.com"

ADD rest_test.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

When running the docker container using the command `docker run -p 80:8080 mywebapp` I get the following output (which seems to be correct to me):

```
docker run -p 80:8080 mywebapp
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.404 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.53
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.407 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 29 2018 14:42:45 UTC
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.408 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.53.0
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.408 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.408 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.0.0-31-generic
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.409 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.409 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7-openjdk/jre
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.409 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.7.0_181-b01
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.410 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.410 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.411 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.411 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.412 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.412 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.412 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.413 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.413 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.413 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.17 using APR version 1.6.3.
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.418 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018)
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.528 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.556 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.561 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1095 ms
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.677 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.677 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.53
21-Oct-2019 16:49:55.760 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/rest_test.war
21-Oct-2019 16:49:56.810 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/rest_test.war has finished in 1,050 ms
21-Oct-2019 16:49:56.820 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sample.war
21-Oct-2019 16:49:56.911 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sample.war has finished in 91 ms
21-Oct-2019 16:49:56.913 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs
21-Oct-2019 16:49:56.986 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished in 73 ms
21-Oct-2019 16:49:56.992 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples
21-Oct-2019 16:49:57.799 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples has finished in 807 ms
21-Oct-2019 16:49:57.801 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
21-Oct-2019 16:49:57.882 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 82 ms
21-Oct-2019 16:49:57.885 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager
21-Oct-2019 16:49:57.984 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 99 ms
21-Oct-2019 16:49:57.993 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
21-Oct-2019 16:49:58.081 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has finished in 88 ms
21-Oct-2019 16:49:58.088 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
21-Oct-2019 16:49:58.156 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
21-Oct-2019 16:49:58.187 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2625 ms
```

**What is working so far** is that the docker container seems to be started correctly and that I can reach the tomcat 'homepage' by entering `localhost` into the browser (see the picture below). Also my .war file seems to be added and extracted correctly (there is a `rest_test.war` file and a `rest_test` directory in the directory `webapps` of the tomcat docker container). Also everything is working just fine when starting it from within eclipse.

[image: Tomcat 'homepage' is reachable]

**What is NOT working yet** is to reach the rest service I created and deployed. I tried to access it using the url `localhost/rest_test/rest/test/hello` but I get an HTTP error 404 - Not Found.

**What is kinda strange** is that I don't get a Message in the HTTP error 404 when calling the url `localhost/rest_test/rest/...`, but I get a message when calling any other url (like shown in the pictures below), which makes me think that it's not completely wrong, what I'm trying.

[image: The 'assumed correct' url doesn't contain a message in the HTTP error 404]

[image: A wrong URL seems to contain a message in the http 404 error]

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Updated to tomcat 9 using the docker image `tomcat:9.0-alpine`, but that didn't seem to change anything. The content of the .war file looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Since jersey 2.26 all modules are build using Java SE 8. The tomcat:8.0-alpine base image instead packs java version 1.7.0_181. You should normally get version incompatibility errors in the logs. Have you checked the content of the war file? In any case I would suggest you update to tomcat 9 unless you have a strong reason not to.

Comment: I updated to tomcat 9.0.2 using the docker image `tomcat:9.0-alpine`, but that doesn't seem to change anything. I'm not shure how the content of the .war file is supposed to look. I'll edit the question and add the content.

Comment: The war does not contain the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. Check the build to make sure the war is created correctly. The `lib` folder should contain the declared maven dependecies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the war file is not built correctly. The `WEB-INF/libs` directory containing the jar application dependencies is missing. More about the directory Layout of a Web Application Archive file [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html).

Exceptions thrown during startup are logged into `/usr/local/tomcat/logs/localhost.<timestamp>.log`. That is the reason everything seems to work normally. `localhost.log` should contain the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

As mentioned in the comments jersey 2.26 cannot run with java 1.7.0_181. As the libraries don't get loaded during application startup, there are no java version incompatibility errors in the output.

Now, assuming you run with tomcat 9 and java 8, the first step is to fix the build. I suggest running maven from command line. Your `pom.xml` looks just fine and it should create a valid war.

Next step is to set the scope of `javax.ws.rs-api` library to provided. The `jersey-bundle` library has a slightly different version of the `javax.ws.rs` classes and if you keep both your may run into classloading issues.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This will fix things but the configuration still has issues because you are mixing jersey 1.x with jersey 2.x libraries. In addition the [jersey-bundle](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle) should not be used with maven. *The bundle is only intended for developers that do not use Maven's dependency system.*

A basic dependency configuration using the jersey 2 libraries should be like the following:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <jersey2.version>2.26</jersey2.version>
    <jaxrs.version>2.1.1</jaxrs.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- JAX-RS -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

The `web.xml` should be modified too:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>net.jfabricationgames.rest_test</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The content of the war file sees to be the problem. If it's built correctly I get an internal server error (HTTP 500) caused by an `AbstractMethodError`. But now I at least got an error and can figure out whats the new problem. Thanks! That helped a lot.

Comment: @Tobias You are mixing jersey 1.x with jersey 2.x libraries. I have updated the answer.

Comment: The updated answer actually fixed all problems! It's working now. Thank you very much!